# Get max logged time of each employee

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the maximum logged time of each student who entered the class from his/her attendance.

```
table name : student_att
id | student_id | checkin_date | checkin_time | type
1  | 1          | 2019-08-04   | 08:25:00     | checkin  
2  | 1          | 2019-08-04   | 09:30:00     | checkin  
3  | 2          | 2019-08-04   | 08:00:00     | checkin  
4  | 2          | 2019-08-04   | 08:30:00     | checkout 
5  | 2          | 2019-08-04   | 09:45:00     | checkout
```

My Query :

```
    SELECT
    student_id,
    checkin_date,
    type,
    MAX (checkin_time) max_time
FROM
    student_att
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    3
ORDER BY
    student_id,
    max_time DESC
```

BUT, I want only max time of each student either "type" may be checkin or checkout. Please help. 
I want result like this :

```
table name : student_att
id | student_id | checkin_date | checkin_time | type
2  | 1          | 2019-08-04   | 09:30:00     | checkin  
5  | 2          | 2019-08-04   | 09:45:00     | checkout
```

Comment: From your database I see Student 1 checked in twice but never checked out ?? And student 2 never checked in but checked out twice ?? :)

Comment: yes, that's might be possible as student might forget to checkout and only do checkins. Also thats just a sample data to explain my problem on query that I am facing. :(

Comment: Also not sure what your group by is attempting to do

Comment: Is this postgresql or mysql?

Comment: I have tried with my own query lets say that's my attempt. Please ignore my tried query, that's not giving the correct result. BTW that's PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

I mention this only because the question was originally tagged MySQL:

In MySQL, you could do this:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM student_att a
  JOIN (SELECT student_id,MAX(checkin_time) checkin_time FROM student_att GROUP BY student_id) b
    ON b.student_id = a.student_id
   AND b.checkin_time = a.checkin_time;
```

Comment: This seems to be working for PostgreSQL as well as I get the correct data result.

Comment: It's possible; I'm not familiar with Postgres, so I couldn't comment.

Comment: @DxTx If so, then that's a Postgres limitation only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Sample Data (These data are slightly different from the original post)

```
CREATE TABLE student_att (
    id int,
    student_id int,
    checkin_date DATE,
    checkin_time time,
    type varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO student_att
VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-08-04' , '08:25:00', 'checkin'),
(2, 1, '2019-08-04' , '09:30:00' , 'checkin'),
(3, 2, '2019-08-04' , '08:00:00' , 'checkin'),  
(4, 2, '2019-09-04' , '08:30:00' , 'checkout'), 
(5, 2, '2019-07-04' , '09:45:00' , 'checkout');
```

Query

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   (SELECT student_id,
               checkin_date,
               Max(checkin_time) AS checkin_time,
               Row_number() OVER (partition BY student_id ORDER BY student_id, checkin_date DESC) AS rn
        FROM   student_att
        GROUP  BY student_id, checkin_date) t1
       INNER JOIN student_att t2
               ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
                  AND t1.checkin_date = t2.checkin_date
                  AND t1.checkin_time = t2.checkin_time
WHERE  t1.rn = 1;
```

Output

```
+-----+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
| id  | student_id  | checkin_date  | checkin_time  |   type   |
+-----+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
|  2  |          1  | 2019-08-04    | 09:30:00      | checkin  |
|  4  |          2  | 2019-09-04    | 08:30:00      | checkout |
+-----+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/56b06/1/0